# Spark Master IP configuration in Azure VM

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, azure-virtual-machine, apache-spark-standalone

I am setting up standalone Spark cluster in Azure VM. I want to run Spark master with Azure VM's public IP not with VM's hostname, so that I can access from other VM.

**Spark version: spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7**

I have created new file "spark-env.sh" under conf folder and added **export SPARK_MASTER_HOST=x.x.x.x**

***Start master***
sbin>./start-master.sh

I am getting below mentioned error. Spark master is not started.

**How to set public IP address to Spark Master ?**

**Error LOG**

```
18/04/10 04:55:12 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: root
18/04/10 04:55:12 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: root
18/04/10 04:55:12 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to:
18/04/10 04:55:12 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to:
18/04/10 04:55:12 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(root); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(root); groups with modify permissions: Set()
18/04/10 04:55:13 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7077. Attempting port 7078.
18/04/10 04:55:13 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7078. Attempting port 7079.
18/04/10 04:55:13 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7079. Attempting port 7080.
18/04/10 04:55:13 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7080. Attempting port 7081.
18/04/10 04:55:13 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7081. Attempting port 7082.
18/04/10 04:55:13 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7082. Attempting port 7083.
18/04/10 04:55:13 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7083. Attempting port 7084.
18/04/10 04:55:13 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7084. Attempting port 7085.
18/04/10 04:55:13 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7085. Attempting port 7086.
18/04/10 04:55:13 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7086. Attempting port 7087.
18/04/10 04:55:13 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7087. Attempting port 7088.
18/04/10 04:55:13 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7088. Attempting port 7089.
18/04/10 04:55:13 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7089. Attempting port 7090.
18/04/10 04:55:13 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7090. Attempting port 7091.
18/04/10 04:55:13 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7091. Attempting port 7092.
18/04/10 04:55:13 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7092. Attempting port 7093.
18/04/10 04:55:13 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7092. Attempting port 7093.
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: Service 'sparkMaster' failed after 16 retries (starting from 7077)! Consider explicitly setting the appropriate port for the service 'sparkMaster' (for example spark.ui.port for SparkUI) to an available port or increasing spark.port.maxRetries.
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:127)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:501)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1218)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:496)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:481)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:210)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:353)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:399)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:446)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

For `SPARK_MASTER_HOST`, you should use VM's private IP or `0.0.0.0`, you could not enter VM's public IP, if you do it, you will get the error log.

Now, you want to access Spark Master by public IP, you need open port `7077-7093`(not sure, depends on your service) on [Azure NSG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-create-nsg-arm-pportal) and VM's firewall.

Comment: You could check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-udr-overview) to know how Azure VNet work. When service is listening on `0.0.0.0`, you could access it on Public IP.